# Supervised machine learning for several coefficient

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a set of items that are each described by 10 precise numbers `n1, .., n10`. I would like to learn the coefficients `k1, .., k10` that should be associated to those numbers to rank them according to my criteria.

In that purpose I created a web application (in php) that shows me two items and ask me which one should be ranked first (it gives the supervision to the machine learning).

**My question :** I can't find a way to learn the ten coefficients at the same time for each case. Do you have any idea on what algorithm I could use ? (neural networks with all the 10 numbers in entry seem to be a good option because it would learn all the coefficient, but I don't know what would be the output of this network as I would like to learn it by comparing the items two by two.)

Comment: If you are expecting a mathematical solution on this, please remove php tag, so that it will reach correct experts ..

Comment: Maybe study a bit more on if Neural nets will be an over kill or not. Also you need to understand the type of attributes and the nature of data to determine the cost function and get a proper training process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural network is fine for this. Your output would be the 10 coefficients. Comparing them "two by two" is nothing that influences the net architecture. Standard neural net training procedure takes care of "comparing the items" (if you want to call it that) itself.

At last, make sure to know if you have linear (single layer perceptron is enough) or non-linear (multilayer perceptron) data.